# Tkinter in Python - Remove widget from active window

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, window, tkinter

I'm trying to remove a Tkinter progress bar widget from an active window (after the GUI window using Tkinter has been initialized). I'm using a Tkinter Frame for my window. I've initialized the progress bar as pb, as below.

```
pb = ttk.Progressbar(root,orient ="horizontal",length = 540, mode ="determinate")
```

And then I've tried two different methods to get rid of the progress bar. The line below causes the window to freeze and stop responding when I try to use it after the GUI is initialized.

```
pb.pack_forget()
```

The line below causes only a middle section of the progress bar to disappear, but you can still see the two sides of it.

```
pb.destroy()
```

Is there any way I could get this widget to disappear after the Frame has been initialized?

Comment: I find it pretty hard to believe that calling `pack_forget()` will cause the window to freeze. Are you saying that if you have a working program, and put in that one single line, the program freezes? Are you by chance using both pack and grid in the same frame?

Comment: You're correct - the problem was that I was using grid configurations too (without even realizing). I've removed these, and now `pack_forget()` does not cause the application to freeze - however I get the same bug as using `destroy()` - part of the progress bar disappears. The section that disappears seems to be the exact same width as the label containing text below it...

Comment: is the event loop running? "part of the progress bar disappears" sounds like the event loop isn't running, so screen redraw requests aren't being honored.

Comment: `root.mainloop()` is running, if this is what you mean by the event loop

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to.

Comment: The event loop is running - I'm not sure why this bug is occurring then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific answer to your question is that `pack_forget`, `grid_forget` or `grid_remove` are what you want if you want to make a widget temporarily invisible. Which one you choose depends on if you're using grid or pack, and whether or not you want grid to remember where it was so you can later put it back in the same spot.

`destroy` is what you want to call if you want to literally destroy the widget.

When used properly, none of those methods will cause your program to freeze. Without seeing your code, it's impossible to know what the root cause of the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my bad English. 
This code worked for me. I simply follow **Oakley's** instruction.

```
def progressBar(*args, **kwargs):

def progress(currentValue):
    progressbar["value"] = currentValue

maxValue = 100

progressbar = ttk.Progressbar((kwargs), orient="horizontal", length=150, mode="determinate", takefocus=True)
progressbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

currentValue = 0
progressbar["value"] = currentValue
progressbar["maximum"] = maxValue

divisions = 10
for i in range(divisions):
    currentValue = currentValue + 10
    progressbar.after(500, progress(currentValue))
    progressbar.update()  # Force an update of the GUI

progressbar.destroy()
```

Hence I simply tried `progressbar.destroy()` outside of the loader loop. So after
complete the loading, it will disappear from the main App window.

Thank you, **Bryan Oakley** sir.